# Clearfix not working on nested columns

Tags: html, css, grid, clearfix

I'm trying to define some rows and columns in my CSS project and all is working quite well except when the viewport is small. To help you understand my problem, I [have this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BorNxQ). And this is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column column-4"></div>
  <div class="column column-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-6"></div>
      <div class="column column-6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column-4"></div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.row, 
.column {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    .column + .column {
        margin-left: 1.6%;
    }

    .column-1 {
        width: 6.86666666667%;
    }

    ...

    .column-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

[class*="column"] {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 2em;
}

[class*="column"] [class*="column"] {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

As you can see, I have a single row with three columns, and the second column have nested columns. All works, but when the windows is small enough, only three rows are showed, instead of four (two main columns and two nested). The last column is drawn over the last nested column. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I don't understand the issue here. http://i.imgur.com/VUPoWXL.png

Comment: If you look to that image, three rows are showed but I have four columns so I expect two grey rows and two blue rows.

Comment: Hmm you set the height on 2em, so it can't be higher. Actually there are 4 rows but the third is behind the last one so you don't see it because of 2em height. Change height to padding and it will work.

Comment: @makshh Oh, stupid of me! I see the problem now. Thanks a lot. Post an answer if you want and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Yes, the last blue one is behind the last column. And the only reason is `height:2em;`.

Comment: @divy3993 Yep, my fault. I was checking row height and that was correct. I was not thinking the the parent height... My fault.

Comment: i suggest the middle column be made in to two columns with class column-2

Comment: Ya see this one : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdopLo. I just added padding to have better look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given height 2em to your columns, which is causing the problem.

Ideally you should not apply fixed height to columns as content may vary from column to column. But if that is your requirement, then in you media query you can do following CSS modifications.

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  [class*="column"] {
    background-color: grey;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 2em;
  }
}
```